# setTransactionRevenue of ProductAction api doesnt reflect correct results in dashboard

Tags: android, google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-firebase, google-analytics-sdk

I am trying to implement google analytics in android from a long time and I am stuck in implementing the final transaction code.
What I have done

MyApp application = (MyApp) getApplication();

```
    Tracker mTracker = application.getDefaultTracker();
    Product product;
    ProductAction productAction = new ProductAction(ProductAction.ACTION_PURCHASE);

    mOrderedItems = mOrderPlaceResponse.getOrderDetails().getItemDetails();
    productAction.setTransactionId(mOrderPlaceResponse.getNumber());

    for (ItemDetail lineItem : mOrderedItems) {
        product = new Product()
                .setId(String.valueOf(lineItem.getDesignId()))
                .setName(lineItem.getTitle()).setQuantity(lineItem.getQuantity());
        product.setPrice(lineItem.getSoldAtPrice())
                .setCategory(lineItem.getType());

        productAction.setProductActionList(lineItem.getSource());
        productAction.setTransactionRevenue(lineItem.getSoldAtPrice() * lineItem.getQuantity());
        HitBuilders.EventBuilder builder = new HitBuilders.EventBuilder()
                .addProduct(product)
                .setProductAction(productAction);
        mTracker.send(builder.build());
    }
```

Ideally the transaction revenue to be sent must be same in all hits for a transaction.
But when I do that the dashboard just shows me the first item sent as part of transaction.